# server reached MaxClients setting, consider raising the MaxClients setting

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

my httpd server is crushing in about 2-3 hours.
i reinstall apache server via whm/easyapache 3-4 times today; but couldnt fix. 
(i just can reboot, to fix now)

i got some errors on /etc/httpd/logs/error_log file(summary is at below). what do you suggest to me? its still getting crushed every 2-3 hours :/

- tons of 'File does not exist' errors.
- '[warn] (101)Network is unreachable: connect to listener on [::]:443' error
- 'Script timed out before returning headers' errors
- server reached MaxClients setting, consider raising the MaxClients setting
- notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
- some 'Invalid method in request \x80g\x01\x03\x01' errors.
- [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `www.xx.com' does NOT match server name!?
- [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/local/apache/bin/suexec)
- [notice] ModSecurity for Apache/2.7.7 (http://www.modsecurity.org/) configured.
- [notice] ModSecurity: APR compiled version="1.4.8"; loaded version="1.4.8"
- [notice] ModSecurity: PCRE compiled version="8.21 "; loaded version="8.21 2011-12-12"
- [notice] ModSecurity: LIBXML compiled version="2.9.0"

**HTTPD.CONF:**

Include "/usr/local/apache/conf/includes/pre_main_global.conf"

Include "/usr/local/apache/conf/includes/pre_main_2.conf"

LoadModule bw_module /usr/local/apache/modules/mod_bw.so

LoadModule frontpage_module modules/mod_frontpage.so

LoadModule bwlimited_module modules/mod_bwlimited.so

LoadModule auth_passthrough_module modules/mod_auth_passthrough.so

Include "/usr/local/apache/conf/mod_bandwidth.conf"

Include "/usr/local/apache/conf/php.conf"

Include "/usr/local/apache/conf/modsec2.conf"

Include "/usr/local/apache/conf/includes/errordocument.conf"

ErrorLog "logs/error_log"

DefaultType text/plain

ScriptAliasMatch ^/?controlpanel/?$ /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/redirect.cgi

ScriptAliasMatch ^/?cpanel/?$ /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/redirect.cgi

ScriptAliasMatch ^/?kpanel/?$ /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/redirect.cgi

ScriptAliasMatch ^/?securecontrolpanel/?$ /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/sredirect.c$

ScriptAliasMatch ^/?securecpanel/?$ /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/sredirect.cgi

ScriptAliasMatch ^/?securewhm/?$ /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/swhmredirect.cgi

ScriptAliasMatch ^/?webmail/?$ /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/wredirect.cgi

ScriptAliasMatch ^/?whm/?$ /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/whmredirect.cgi

Alias /bandwidth /usr/local/bandmin/htdocs/

Alias /img-sys /usr/local/cpanel/img-sys/

Alias /java-sys /usr/local/cpanel/java-sys/

Alias /mailman/archives /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/mailman/archives/public/

Alias /pipermail /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/mailman/archives/public/

Alias /sys_cpanel /usr/local/cpanel/sys_cpanel/

ScriptAlias /cgi-sys /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/

ScriptAlias /mailman /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/mailman/cgi-bin/

ScriptAlias /scgi-bin /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/scgiwrap

---

**SYSCTL.CONF**

net.ipv4.ip_forward = 0

net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 1

net.ipv4.conf.default.accept_source_route = 0

kernel.sysrq = 0

net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 1

kernel.msgmnb = 65536

kernel.msgmax = 65536

kernel.shmmax = 68719476736

kernel.shmall = 4294967296

**LIMITS.CONF**

```
# /etc/security/limits.conf
#Each line describes a limit for a user in the form:
#<domain>        <type>  <item>  <value>#Where:
#<domain> can be: #        - an user name #        - a group name, with @group syntax #        - the wildcard *, for default entry #        - the wildcard %, can be also used with %group syntax, #                 for maxlogin limit #<type> can have the two values: #        - "soft" for enforcing the soft limits #        - "hard" for enforcing hard limits
```

etc etc... it s to hard to write here :S

Comment: There are several places you need to tune. Can you post here the abbreviated contents of `httpd.conf`, `/etc/security/limits.conf` and `/etc/sysctl.conf`? Can you also post the O/S?

Comment: hi alits, i coulnd write all. but, i editted the question. you can find first part of httpd.conf, limits.conf and sysctl.conf there. my op system is: centos. and using whm/cpanel..

Comment: I don't see maxclients and related settings on the httpd.conf you posted. The kernel parameters for network related settings are set to defaults. You should bump up the following, net.core.rmem_default, net.core.wmem_default, net.core.wmem_max, net.core.rmem_max. You also need to bump up the limits.

Comment: i couldnt find maxclients on httpd.conf.. but, when i check via WHM / pache cofiguration, it says: maxclients = 150 (default)

Comment: there should be something wrong. my sites cant get max limits :S

Comment: What kind of MPM (apache multiprocessing module) do you have? worker MPM or prefork MPM? I will suggest a setting based on which one you have.

Comment: when i type TOP comment to ssh, it shows: mysql has 200% cpu usage(!)..

Comment: Question is off topic for SO, but have you actually *tried* raising [MaxClients](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html#maxclients) as suggested in the log message?

Comment: it doesnt help.. MaxClients is at max limit.

Comment: i have the same problem. And a lot of Invalid method in request \x16\x03\x03 erros as wel. Could this be a bad WHM update? This started in Januari.
Have you found any solution yet?

Comment: i dont know; my problem recovered a day later by itself :S

Comment: and its happening now, again :(